# Select Range up until specific data VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help here, need to extract to different files selected data in image.

Example: first file should have the name HHNAJRXZ8811090123 with the data from that booking, second file with AJRHAJXZ8812090123 with that booking data, and so on.

Thank you so much in advance.

I'm kind of lost here as every file are different, the format is always the same but can have 1 to several bookings.

[image]

Comment: There is no image in your question. Can you edit it so that we can see what you are referring to?

Comment: Do you want to end up with a file called  HHNAJRXZ8811090123.xlsx Which just has the data from `A5:E10` in `A1:E6`, and so on, or what is the kind of output you are looking for? How much of the process are you looking to automate?

Comment: Hi @ChristoferWeber, yes, somewhat that, file 1 with A1:E10 with the name from A3, file 2 with data on A1 and A12:E20 with name on A12 and so on... the thing is every file has different entries, can hav 5bookings or 50....

Comment: Hi @MikeWasos, can you now see the picture?

Comment: Yes, now is visible. Thanks